# How to define all numbers(int, float with whitesapce) from python string via regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings with numbers: integers, floats (might be with whitespace). I need to get only numbers in the right way

```
t = ['составляет 629 688, ', 'ценах составляет 337, ', ' 8 000 рублей, ', ' 589,5 147375 ),']
```

from this list, I need to get

- 629688
- 337
- 8000
- 589.5
- 147375

my script looks like:

```
all_nums = []
for text in [re.sub('(?<=\d)+ (?=\d)+', '', ele.replace(',', '.')) for ele in t]:   
    for num in re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?', text):
        all_nums.append(float(num))
print(all_nums)
```

it returns

```
[629688.0, 337.0, 8000.0, 589.5147375]
```

but I need in this way:

[629688.0, 337.0, 8000.0, 589.5, 147375]

Could anyone help me, pls

Comment: How is one supposed to know when a space is *part* of a number and when it *separates* numbers?

Comment: I tested your regex by itself with your final string; the output is `' 589.5147375 ).'`. You are removing all spaces. Your regex needs to account for the two different cases where a space will separate numbers or not. We can't know what format all your data is in, so it's hard to say if there's a simple way to differentiate those cases. I suggest using https://regex101.com/ to test out your regex.

Comment: Did the answer below help?

Answer (score 0):

```
all_nums = []
for s in t:
    for match in re.findall('(\d[\d ]*(?:,\d*)?)', s): 
        all_nums.append(float(match.replace(" ", "").replace(",", ".")))
print(all_nums)
```